# NativeScript-Vue zoom image

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I am working on a basic app that has a list of items and when an item is selected its corresponding image is show in an image tag.Issue is, the images are very "wide" and hence appear very small. I am trying to somehow enable the zoom functionality on the image for the user. I checked all "stretch" options but "pinch" and "zoom" are not working. According to official documentation, i looked at decodeHeight and decodeWidth but they do not appear to be working as well.
I appreciate any help i can get, Following is the code:

```html
    <template>
    
        <Page class="page">
            <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar" />
            <ScrollView>`enter code here`
                <StackLayout class="home-panel">
                    <Image :src="img_src" strech="AspectFill"/>
                    <ListView for="images in img_data" @itemTap="onButtonTap" style="height:200vh">
                        <v-template>
                            <Label :text="images.name" />
                        </v-template>
                    </ListView>
                    <!-- <Button text="Button" @tap="onButtonTap" /> -->
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </Page>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            onButtonTap(event) {
                console.log(event.index);
                this.img_src = "~/components/" + this.img_data[event.index].image;
    
            }
        },
    
        data() {
            return {
                img_src: "",
                img_data: [
                    { name: "Iron Man", image: "iron_man.png" },
                    { name: "super man", image: "super_man.png" },
                    { name: "Batman", image: "batman.png" },
                    { name: "Flash", image: "flash.png" },
                ]
            };
        }
    };
    
    </script>
    
    
    <style scoped>
        .home-panel {
            vertical-align: top;
            padding-top: 20;
            font-size: 20;
            margin: 15;
        }
    
        .description-label {
            margin-bottom: 15;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: The default image component doesn't have the zoom feature you will need a plugin for that check out https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-image-zoom

Comment: Thanks, i am still learning NS so if you could help me demonstrate on how to use this in my script, it would be great!

Answer (score 1):

First, install `nativescript-image-zoom` plugin:

```
tns plugin add nativescript-image-zoom
```

Then [globally register](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html) the `ImageZoom` element in your `main.js`:

```
Vue.registerElement('ImageZoom', () => require('nativescript-image-zoom').ImageZoom);
```

Now you can use it as a global component anywhere in your app you want.

```
<ImageZoom v-if="ifStatement"
           :src="imageSrc"
           class="main-image" />
```

Keep in mind that while global registration of the component doesn't hurt the performance, it prevents you from lazy loading the element.

Answer (score 0):

Install the plugin by running the following command

```
tns plugin add nativescript-image-zoom
```

Replace your Image tag with this custom component

```
<StackLayout class="home-panel">
                <ui:ImageZoom :src="img_src" strech="AspectFill"/>
                <ListView for="images in img_data" @itemTap="onButtonTap" style="height:200vh">
                    <v-template>
                        <Label :text="images.name" />
                    </v-template>
                </ListView>
                <!-- <Button text="Button" @tap="onButtonTap" /> -->
            </StackLayout>
```

Don't forget to add xmlns to your Page element.

```
xmlns:ui="nativescript-image-zoom"
```

In case you have any another question, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: thanks, where do i add this in the code?"xmlns:ui="nativescript-image-zoom"

Comment: Here is the example <Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo" loaded="onLoaded"
  xmlns:ui="nativescript-image-zoom 
  xmlns:accept="views/accept" 
  xmlns:messages="views/messages" 
  xmlns:favourite="views/favourite">

Comment: Thanks again, but which file do i edit in order to add this. sorry for such noob questions.

Comment: in the same file where you are planning to add that component.
<template>

    <Page class="page" xmlns:ui="nativescript-image-zoom" >
        <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar" />
        <ScrollView>`enter code here`

Comment: what is xmlns:ui _?